# BigQuery extract from JSON with special charactors - slash and dot

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a column (string data type) in which actually stores the JSON data. See the sample line below.

```
{
    "labels": {
        "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "my_vm-01"
    }
}
```

I can run `JSON_EXTRACT(column,'$.labels)` to extract it. But I want to extract the `compute.googleapis.com/resource_name` key.

I tried these things.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(rawline, '$.labels.compute.googleapis.com/resource_name') FROM `bhuvi.tbl`

Error: Invalid token in JSONPath at: /resource_name
```

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(rawline, '$.labels."compute.googleapis.com/resource_name"') FROM `bhuvi.tbl`

Error: Invalid token in JSONPath at: ."compute.googleapis.com/resource_name"
```

How can I do this with Bigquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> still looking for a better solution

You can use just one JSON_EXTRACT as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(rawline, "$.labels['compute.googleapis.com/resource_name']")
FROM `bhuvi.tbl`
```

Answer (score 1):

Im able to solve this by using the double quote and extract twice. Leaving it as an answer, so others can benefit from this,

### but still looking for a better solution.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(rawline,'$.labels'), "$['compute.googleapis.com/resource_name']") FROM `bhuvi.tbl`
```