# Json path with space for JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR function

Tags: json, google-bigquery, jsonpath

I'm working with a json data in BigQuery and tries to extract a value from a nested object. The json looks like something below.

```
  {
   "integrations": {
    "Actions Target": {
      "session_id": 1673497743430
    },
  },
```

My goal is to extract the session Id. I tried a number of approaches but all failed with json path error.

- json_extract_scalar(data, '$.integrations.''Action Target''.session_id')
- json_extract_scalar(data, '$.integrations.'Action Target'.session_id')
- json_extract_scalar(data, '$.integrations["Action Target"].session_id')
- json_extract_scalar(data, '$["integrations"]["Action Target"]["session_id"]')

Would anyone please advise?

Comment: use *JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, "$.integrations.Actions Target.session_id")*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656621/bigquery-extract-from-json-with-special-charactors-slash-and-dot